# How to use a curve modifier in-game (work around)

Tags: animation, game-engine, modifiers, workflow, bezier-curves

I have some cords that have a curve modifier on them so that they don't stick straight out of a robots leg. The problem occurs when animating. since one end of the cord is attached to the leg, and another to the body, the cord will need to deform. Is there a way I can make the cord update to its new positions realtime? I would try this with shape-keys, but animating them never seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use curves as they are not supported. But you can get the effect your are looking for via armature.

Create an armature to control your cord. Parent the cord via Armature Deform to the armature `<ctrl+p>`.

[image]

In pose mode add an IK-constraints to the top bone.
[image]

You will see the cord will follow the target in preview. To make it do the same thing in the bge use the armature actuator.
[image]

If you move the target while running the game, the cord should follow as much as it can.

[image]

I hope it helps